# How would running a program manually vs running a program from visual studio differ?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm having an issue with a windows ce application. It runs fine through the visual studio interface by clicking the "start debugging (F5)" in the visual studio interface.

However, if I try to run that deployed executable manually from the emulator I get a `MissingMethodException`.  This only happens when compiling a release version of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in deployed dependencies.  Studio pushes down everything it thinks is required to be there - the CF itself and references.  It pushes most of them right to the app's folder, which is where the loader starts looking for dependencies.

To be 100% clear on your question, if you debug the exact same app, it works fine, but if, immediately after quitting that deployed app, you run it manually from the same location that Studio deployed to (by verifying that in the Project Properties), the application won't run?  I mean with absolutely no recompiling, no device reset, no other file copying, etc?

Comment: that is correct, simply exiting out of the program and attempting to start it back up again manually from the emulator and it throws the missing method exception.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why, but there was an awful lot of work happening in the `ctor` of one of the classes, once I moved that work out, it seems to be working fine now, however I'm still not sure why I was able to start it in via visual studio and not manually.

Comment: Interesting.  It's almost certainly a low-memory condition - the CF might throw a MME when it fails to load the method due to not having enough space to JIT it.  I should have thought about that for my answer - it's just I see it so rarely. Why Studio would change that, I'm not certain - must have to do with load order and fragmentation.